# Add a panel in shiny that disappears on time

Tags: r, shiny

I need to place a text panel in my shiny app that disappears 10 seconds after it starts (like an advice), anyone know if it is posible? I've tryed to use the command "invalidLater", but it always appear again.

Thanks

Louro, J.

Comment: Look into `shinyBS` package here https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Modals.html#bsModal

Comment: you can put something like `invalidateLater(1e4, session); if ((active <<- exists('active'))) return()` at the beginning of a `renderUI` and the `uiOutput` will just show up for 10 seconds.

Comment: using `<<-` is discouraged in general, but is especially dangerous in shiny apps, because it completely ruins the app for multiple concurrent users, since users will interfere with each others' variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @bunk is showing a good way is to use invalidateLater, here's some examples:

```
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(
        HTML(
          '
          Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("registerTimer", function(message){
            console.log("Timer registered for $("+message.selector+")with delay "+message.delay);
            setTimeout(removeElementFromDOM, message.delay, message.selector);
          });

          function removeElementFromDOM(selector){
            $("#"+selector).remove();
          }
          '
        )
      )
    ),
    uiOutput("ui1"),
    textOutput("ui2"),
    plotOutput("plt1"),
    div(id="txtDiv","Some text here")
  )
)

rm(active) 
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){
  data <- data.frame("x"=runif(10),"y"=runif(10))
  txt1 <- "Some text"
  makeReactiveBinding('txt1')
  makeReactiveBinding('data')

  # Remove with javascript
  session$sendCustomMessage('registerTimer',
    message=list(selector='txtDiv',delay=4000))

  # Hide with shinyjs
  output$plt1 <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(data)){
      hide("plt1")
    } else{
      plot(x~y,data)
    }
  })
  output$ui2 <- renderText({
    txt1
  })

  # Continously update, output nothing after time
  output$ui1 <- renderUI({
    invalidateLater(1000, session); 
    if ((active <<- exists('active'))) return()
    div("Text here")
  })

  # Triggers change
  reactiveTimer(2000,{
    txt1 <- NULL
  })

  reactiveTimer(3000,{
    data <- NULL
  })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

`ui1` uses the invalidateLater method, `ui2` uses a reactive value that is set to NULL and `plt1` is a variation of ui2 where shinyjs is used to hide the plotOutput.

**Edited**

I've added a Javascript solution to this you can use it on any element of the DOM.

Comment: nicely done.  I do wonder though if this is the best way available?  I was trying some experiments with `withReactiveDomain` trying to something like an `invalidateLater` entirely disappear, if that makes sense.  This bothers me because it keeps invalidating indefinetly.  I couldn't figure out how to make it work though...

Comment: Thank you! that's a great question (and yes, the invalidation isn't all that great), I have to think about that

Comment: Ill try to formulate a question and hopefully post it later today, from the reading the docs it seems like it should be possible to create a dummy reactive enviroment, create some reactive elements inside of it, then destroy them and the environment.  But so far, the app just crashes when I try this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it suits perfectly for what I was looking for.

Comment: using `<<-` is discouraged in general, but is especially dangerous in shiny apps, because it completely ruins the app for multiple concurrent users, since users will interfere with each others' variables

Comment: instead, use `reactiveValues` for storing program states